# EN-GB hyphenation not working in LibreOffice 5.1.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice, 16.04, hunspell

Hyphenation for EN-GB language text on LibreOffice 5.1.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 does not work anymore. When I change it to EN-US everything works as it is supposed to.

Checking under `Tools > Options > Language settings -> Writing aids` lists three loaded modules:

- Hunspell SpellChecker
- Libhyphen Hyphenator
- OpenOffice.org New Thesaurus

Clicking on `Edit` shows me that there is no "Hyphenator" module loaded for EN-GB. For EN-US, however, it shows `Libhyphen Hyphenator`.

`hunspell-en-gb` is successfully installed.

Everything worked normally till I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled `hunspell-en-gb` and restarted(!) the system. Now it works!